# If $ \ln z=-1.203-i \frac{2 \pi}{3}$ , then find $z$

Tags: complex-analysis

> If  $\ln z=-1.203-i \frac{2 \pi}{3}$, find $z$.

I have no idea how to solve when  $ \ln $ is involved in the problem to find the solution. But I know that $ \ln (z)=\ln |z|+i\arg(z) $. This gives us  $ -1.203-i \frac{2 \pi}{3}=\ln (\sqrt{1.203^{2}+\frac{4 \pi^{2}}{9}})+i\arg (z) $. But from that point how to approach further?

Comment: $\overline{z} = e^{-1.203 - i \frac{2\pi}{3}}$

Comment: Any further simplification can be done.

Comment: "This gives us  $ -1.203-i \frac{2 \pi}{3}=\ln (\sqrt{1.203^{2}+\frac{4 \pi^{2}}{9}})+i* arg (z) $" No, "this would give us" $\ln\left( -1.203-i \frac{2 \pi}{3}\right)=\ln (\sqrt{1.203^{2}+\frac{4 \pi^{2}}{9}})+i* arg (z) $ (and anyway, this is not useful to solve your question).

Answer (score 1):

Let, $z=re^{i\theta}\implies\ln z=\ln r+i\theta$.

So, $\ln r=-1.203\implies r=0.3\quad$ and, $\quad \theta=-\dfrac{2\pi}{3}$.

Therefore, $z=0.3e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{3}}=0.3\left(\cos\dfrac{2\pi}{3}-i\sin\dfrac{2\pi}{3}\right)=0.3\left(-\dfrac12-i\dfrac{\sqrt3}{2}\right)=-0.15-0.26i$